# How to get the preview in xls?

Tags: struts2, ireport

I'm using the below code for get the output in xls.

```java
else if ("xls".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype)) {
        try
        {

            System.out.println("inside xls1");

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        System.out.println("inside xls2");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""
                + strId + ".xls\"");
        System.out.println("inside xls3");
        exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
        System.out.println("inside xls4");
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
                jasperPrint);
        System.out.println("inside xls5");
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,
                ouputStream);
        System.out.println("inside xls6");

        System.out.println("inside exporter for XLS: "+exporter);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("inside xls catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But it's occurred below error.

> Struts Problem Report              Struts has detected an unhandled
>   exception:                 Messages:  No result defined for action
>   com.coin.fk.SalesAction and result Exception
>   File: file:/D:/blm/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/blm/WEB-INF/classes/struts.transaction.xml
>   Line number:  44   Column number: 77

```java
            <action name="salesAction_*" method="{1}" class="com.coin.fk.SalesAction">      
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack"/>     
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
```

Stacktraces

> No result defined for action com.coin.fk.SalesAction and result Exception - action - file:/D:/blm/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/blm/WEB-INF/classes/struts.transaction.xml:44:77
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:350)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
>       org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
>       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
>       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> You are seeing this page because development mode is enabled. Development mode, or devMode, enables extra debugging behaviors and reports to assist developers. To disable this mode, set:
>     struts.devMode=false
>   in your WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties file.

How can I face this issue.
Pls help how to debug this error.

Comment: @AleksandrM, did you add your answer editing the original question ??

Comment: I had the doubt that the "devMode" part was your :)

Answer (score 0):

It does seems you are trying to configure `Global Exceptions` without having a `Global Result` name `Exception`.

Something like this:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="exception">jsp/error.jsp</result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception"
        result="exception" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

in this specific order.

It seems that you have two Interceptors Stack too, one with your custom Interceptor, and the Default Stack. You should use only one stack, with all the Interceptors you need, to avoid executing them two times on each request:

```
 <action name="salesAction_*" method="{1}" class="com.coin.fk.SalesAction">      
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack"/>     
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">   
            <!--result ecc...-->
 </action>
```

should become

```
 <action name="salesAction_*" method="{1}" class="com.coin.fk.SalesAction">      
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultLoginStack"/>     
            <!--result ecc...-->
 </action>
```